# Create user script with variable domain user login

Tags: sql, sql-server, release, release-management, dacpac

We have a DACPAC that has a create user script.
The user has a log in that needs to be set to a windows domain user
When we do a build for Test/Staging/Release we need to be able to apply a different domain and user for the users log in.

I thought we might be able to use SQLCMD variables but I just get a SQL71501 Error when trying to use this That script looks something like this:

```
CREATE USER [Username]
    For Login [$(SQLLoginDomain)]
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [SCHEMANAME]
GO
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up solving this by using a post deployment script in the dacpac and as long as you do a check before trying to call the user to see if they already exist it all works as that is the only place you can use them bar the pre deployment script.

Answer (score 1):

My advice based on bitter experience is to keep anything that is environment specific out of your SQL Server Database Project. Rather, apply anything that is environment specific (permisins etc) as a separate T-SQL script after the DACPAC has been deployed. If you are doing this with Release Management I have a soup-to-nuts blog series that includes publishing DACPACs and separate permissions scripts [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs/).The post about applying a tokenised permissions script is [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-building-deployment-pipeline-using-agent-based-release-template/).

Comment: thanks but we found away to get it where we wanted it but i can imagen it might get very hard to keep track of doing how we did

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Windows domain from the [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) system view.

For example, you could put something like this in the DACPAC's post-deployment script...

```
DECLARE @host_name nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @nt_domain nvarchar(128);

SELECT
    @host_name = host_name,
    @nt_domain = nt_domain
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE
    session_id = @@SPID;

-- If the domain is present, setup the login/user.
-- Otherwise, we are probably running under test environment, so we can skip this.
-- `@nt_domain = @host_name` tends to hold for LocalDB.

IF @nt_domain IS NOT NULL AND @nt_domain <> @host_name BEGIN

    DECLARE @user_nonquoted nvarchar(128) = @nt_domain + '\YourUserName';
    DECLARE @user nvarchar(128) = QUOTENAME(@user_nonquoted);

    IF @user_nonquoted NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals)
        EXEC ('CREATE LOGIN ' + @user + ' FROM WINDOWS');
    IF @user_nonquoted NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals)
        EXEC ('CREATE USER ' + @user + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @user);

END
```